# SQLAlchemy enum in external file

Tags: python, postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy

I have Postgres DB with a table of pending operations.  One column in the operation in an enum with the status of the enum.  I used the standard python (2.7) enum, with AutoNumber (myenum.py):

```
class AutoNumber(enum.Enum):
    def __new__(cls):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

class MyStatus(AutoNumber):

    INITIAL = ()
    ACCEPTED = ()
    DENIED = ()
    ACK_PENDING = ()
    AUTHORIZED = ()
    ACTIVE = ()
    END = ()
    DELETED = ()
# end enum
```

The table looks like (also in myenum.py):

```
Base = declarative_base()

class MyOperation(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'operations'

    id  = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )

    status = Column( Enum(MyStatus) )
    status_message = Column( String )
    status_time = Column( DateTime )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<MyOperation(%s, %s, %s, %s)>" % \
            ( self.id, self.status, self.status_time, self.status_message )
# end class
```

Generally this works fine.  In the SAME FILE that defines MyStatus (myoper.py), I can change the status and save it back to the DB and it works fine:

```
def checkOper( oper ):
    oper.status = MyStatus.DENIED
    oper.status_message = "failed check (internal)"
    oper.status_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

Here's how I call it (within myoper.py)

```
    checkOper( oper )
    session.add(oper)
    session.commit()
```

This is all in the same file (myoper.py).

However, if I pass an oper object to an external function, and IT changes the status, then I get a sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError.

Here's the external function (myoper_test.py):

```
import datetime
from myoper import MyStatus

def extCheckOper( oper ):
    oper.status = MyStatus.DENIED
    oper.status_message = "failed check (external)"
    oper.status_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

Here's how I call it (from myoper.py):

```
    from myoper_test import extCheckOper
    extCheckOper( oper )
    session.add(oper)
    session.commit()
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myoper.py", line 120, in <module>
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 906, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 461, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 441, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2177, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2297, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2261, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 389, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 548, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 177, in save_obj
    mapper, table, update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 737, in _emit_update_statements
    execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1121, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1116, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 639, in _init_compiled
    for key in compiled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 639, in <genexpr>
    for key in compiled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1446, in process
    value = self._db_value_for_elem(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1354, in _db_value_for_elem
    '"%s" is not among the defined enum values' % elem)
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (exceptions.LookupError) "MyStatus.DENIED" is not among the defined enum values [SQL: u'UPDATE operations SET status=%(status)s, status_message=%(status_message)s, status_time=%(status_time)s WHERE operations.id = %(operations_id)s'] [parameters: [{'status': <MyStatus.DENIED: 6>, 'status_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18, 20, 22, 44, 350035), 'status_message': 'failed check (external)', 'operations_id': 3}]]
```

I've tried inspecting the type both in the internal file, and external file, but it's ways listed as `<enum 'MyStatus'>`.

I have found, that if I assign the oper.status to the enum .name, then that DOES work:

```
def extCheckOper( oper ):
    oper.status = MyStatus.AUTHORIZED.name
    oper.status_message = "authorized check (external)"
    oper.status_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

But that's obviously pretty ugly.

So - what am I doing wrong?  What is different about MyStatus in the file it's defined in, vs an external file that screws up SQL Alchemy?

Comment: python2 dont have builtin enum type, are you using enum34 package?

Comment: yes, this is enum34.

Answer (score 3):

I posted this question to the SQL Alchemy mailing list and got an answer.  [Link to thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/16vZm8iBmdU)

Turns out this one of those "gotcha's" about python and has nothing really to do with SQL Alchemy.  Here's a reference: [Executing Main Module Twice](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#executing-the-main-module-twice).

In this particular case, when I executed my script, the MyStatus was created with a particular id (python handle on the type).  But when myoper_test imported MyStatus from myoper, it was created AGAIN with a different id.

So when the extCheckOper assigned a MyStatus value to the status field, it was a *different* MyStatus than SQL Alchemy created the DB mapping with, so when SQL Alchemy tried to save it to the DB, the " is " operator failed, since the (external) MyStatus was different than (original) MyStatus.

There are a couple of different workarounds.  One way is to not run the code as main (after moving exiting **main** code into main() function):

```
$ python -c "from myoper import main; import sys; main(*sys.argv[1:])" ext_check 1
```

The better solution is to avoid this problem entirely - move the code that calls out externally to an internal test script.  The code in **main** stays within mainly within the main script (sorry, couldn't resist... :-) ).